# How to Add two arrays in one soap object for billing and shipping address in magento?

Tags: web-services, api, magento, soap

I am using magento soap api to add shipping and billing address as

" SoapObject item1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntity");

```
          PropertyInfo pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("mode");
          pinfo.setValue("shipping");
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
         item1.addProperty(pinfo);

          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("firstname");
          pinfo.setValue(firstname1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);



          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("lastname");
          pinfo.setValue(lastname1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);


          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("company");
          pinfo.setValue(company1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);



          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("street");
          pinfo.setValue(street1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);



          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("city");
          pinfo.setValue(city1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);



          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("region");
          pinfo.setValue(region1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);



          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("postcode");
          pinfo.setValue(postcode1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);



          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("country_id");
          pinfo.setValue(country1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);



          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("telephone");
          pinfo.setValue(telephone1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);



          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("fax");
          pinfo.setValue(fax1);
          pinfo.setType(String.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);



          pinfo = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo.setName("is_default_shipping");
          pinfo.setValue(1);
          pinfo.setType(Integer.class);
          item1.addProperty(pinfo);







          SoapObject entityArray = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntityArray");
          entityArray.addProperty("customer",item1);
```

SoapObject item2 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingC");

```
          PropertyInfo pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("mode");
          pinfo1.setValue("billing");
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
         item2.addProperty(pinfo1);

          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("firstname");
          pinfo1.setValue(firstname1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);



          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("lastname");
          pinfo1.setValue(lastname1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);


          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("company");
          pinfo1.setValue(company1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);



          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("street");
          pinfo1.setValue(street1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);



          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("city");
          pinfo1.setValue(city1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);



          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("region");
          pinfo1.setValue(region1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);



          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("postcode");
          pinfo1.setValue(postcode1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);



          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("country_id");
          pinfo1.setValue(country1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);



          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("telephone");
          pinfo1.setValue(telephone1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);



          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("fax");
          pinfo1.setValue(fax1);
          pinfo1.setType(String.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);



          pinfo1 = new PropertyInfo();
          pinfo1.setName("is_default_billing");
          pinfo1.setValue(0);
          pinfo1.setType(Integer.class);
          item2.addProperty(pinfo1);

          SoapObject entityArray2 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntityArray");
          entityArray2.addProperty("customer",item2);


          Log.e("itemsad2222", entityArray2.toString());

          SoapObject entityArray3 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntityArray");
          entityArray3.addProperty("customer",entityArray);
          entityArray3.addProperty("customer",entityArray2);

      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCustomerAddresses");
      request.addProperty("sessionId", SessionId);
      request.addProperty("quoteId", CartId);
      request.addProperty("customer",entityArray3);"
```

but its not adding and giving exception **customer address data is empty**

Help me out please...it took a day but i still could not find anythng

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you want to add customer billing/shipping address during order creation via SOAP.

You need to pass addresses data using array. for details [click here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.order.html) and take a look at magento's official SOAP doc.

```
$user = 'apiUser';
$password = 'apiKey';
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login($user, $password);
    $cartId = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate($sessionId, 1);
    // load the customer list and select the first customer from the list
    $customerList = $proxy->customerCustomerList($sessionId, array());
    $customer = (array) $customerList[0];
    $customer['mode'] = 'customer';
    $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerSet($sessionId, $cartId, $customer);
    // load the product list and select the first product from the list
    $productList = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId);
    $product = (array) $productList[0];
    $product['qty'] = 1;
    $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, $cartId, array($product));

    $address = array(
        array(
            'mode' => 'shipping',
            'firstname' => $customer['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $customer['lastname'],
            'street' => 'street address',
            'city' => 'city',
            'region' => 'region',
            'telephone' => 'phone number',
            'postcode' => 'postcode',
            'country_id' => 'country ID',
            'is_default_shipping' => 0,
            'is_default_billing' => 0
        ),
        array(
            'mode' => 'billing',
            'firstname' => $customer['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $customer['lastname'],
            'street' => 'street address',
            'city' => 'city',
            'region' => 'region',
            'telephone' => 'phone number',
            'postcode' => 'postcode',
            'country_id' => 'country ID',
            'is_default_shipping' => 0,
            'is_default_billing' => 0
        ),
    );
     // add customer address
    $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($sessionId, $cartId, $address);
    // add shipping method
    $proxy->shoppingCartShippingMethod($sessionId, $cartId, 'flatrate_flatrate');

    $paymentMethod =  array(
        'po_number' => null,
        'method' => 'checkmo',
        'cc_cid' => null,
        'cc_owner' => null,
        'cc_number' => null,
        'cc_type' => null,
        'cc_exp_year' => null,
        'cc_exp_month' => null
    );
     // add payment method
    $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($sessionId, $cartId, $paymentMethod);
     // place the order
    $orderId = $proxy->shoppingCartOrder($sessionId, $cartId, null, null);
```

Comment: I am able to provide adress and then after its giving exception shipping method is not available..? i searched alot didnt find any specific answer can you plz help me out in this?

Comment: need to enable Flat Rate shipping method. because this script is using Flat Rate shipping method look this line `$proxy->shoppingCartShippingMethod($sessionId, $cartId, 'flatrate_flatrate');` here `flatrate_flatrate` means to Flat Rate shipping method.

Comment: yes sir i have enabled flatrate, i am also getting shipping method list as flat rate but when i set shipping method as flatrate_flatrate in my java code it throws me the exception that shipping method is not available

Comment: request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
      "shoppingCartShippingMethod");
    request.addProperty("sessionId", SessionId);
    request.addProperty("quoteId", CartId);
    request.addProperty("shippingMethod", "freeshipping_freeshipping");

    Log.e("shippingrespomnse...", request.toString());

    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);

    SoapObject methodset;
    methodset = (SoapObject) env.getResponse();

Comment: Hi  @Shikhar did you found any solution to this, am also getting same issue (customer address data is empty ) please let me know the solution .Thanks :)

Comment: @syed hey man i searched but couldnt get anythng did you got some stuffs to move ?